# Is there a way with AWS Cognito using Social IdP to signify to the client that the user just signed up?

Tags: aws-lambda, google-analytics, oauth, amazon-cognito, amplifyjs

I have AWS Cognito configured to allow authentication to my app via Google as an identity provider.

When a new user is signed up via the Google login the callback URL is the same for users that are logging in so I have no clear way to determine in the app if the user was a new signup or not.

This is a problem as our Google Analytics event for sign ups can't be fired so it's skewing the signup tracking numbers (even though signups are fine)

Is there a way to pass data from Cognito back to the app (probably via the callback URL) that would allow me to see whether the user was signed up using Lambda triggers?